# Read a file without requiring any module (not even inbuilts)

Tags: node.js

I recently came across a question and got me thinking on how do it. The question is a Competition Question and I do not intend to participate but the question is quite intriguing.

Basically they want to read a file.txt and find a word in there from the input, but

```
It is not allowed to require any JS modules, not even the standard ones built into Node.js
```

this line makes me wonder, how do i read a file in JS.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to pipe the file to node: `cat foo.txt | node foo.js`

**foo.js:**

```
var buf = '';
process.stdin.on('data', function(chunk) {
  buf += chunk;
}).on('end', function() {
  if (buf.indexOf('word') !== -1)
    console.log('Found word!');
  else
    console.log('Did not find word!');
}).resume();
```

Comment: I was thinking that too... but i dont think there is any other solution to that.